# How to install AzureAD in azure powershell function?

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

I am trying to run Get-AzureADApplication in azure powershell function.

I have added `'AzureAD' = '2.*'` in `requirements.psd1`

I have added `Import-Module AzureAD` in `profile.ps1`

but I am getting error as below

`The Function app may be missing a module containing the 'Get-AzureADApplication' command definition. If this command belongs to a module available on the PowerShell Gallery, add a reference to this module to requirements.psd1. Make sure this module is compatible with PowerShell 7. For more details, see https://aka.ms/functions-powershell-managed-dependency. If the module is installed but you are still getting this error, try to import the module explicitly by invoking Import-Module just before the command that produces the error: this will not fix the issue but will expose the root cause.`

I am publishing the function app using vscode

Not sure what I am missing here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you read error?  Did you try doing the Invoke to get more details?

Comment: Yes, it didn't help

Comment: No additional messages?

Comment: I get message "The Function app may be missing the 'AzureAD' module. If 'AzureAD' is available on the PowerShell Gallery, add a reference to this module to requirements.psd1. Make sure this module is compatible with PowerShell 7. For more details, see https://aka.ms/functions-powershell-managed-dependency."

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps to install `AzureAD` using PowerShell.

- Open PowerShell as administrator and run the below commands.

```
Install-Module -Name AzureAD
```

[image]

```
 Import-Module AzureAD
```

[image]

Now check the `azureAD` module is installed or not with
`Get-Module -ListAvailable AzureAD` .

[image]

Now I am trying to run `Get-AzureADApplication`, got the below error.

[image]

Use the below command to login to `azureAD`

```
Connect-AzureAD
Get-AzureADApplication
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying Azure functions with powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I did this there were some changes you had to make to the functionapp to use the AzureAd module.

I created a github project with those changes:

https://github.com/brettmillerb/azureadFunction

The readme in the project shows the function configuration changes to make.

You also have to call out to the Windows PowerShell to utilise the module.

`Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell`

You can see the code in `run.ps1` within the repository